# how to set app background running time in iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am developing a navigation app, that needs to run in the background. I want to know how can I set background running time of app? And is this time fix by iOS?

Comment: What do you mean by "background running time"?

Comment: Do you use external accessories?

Comment: do u want like alarm clock time. or what

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the UIBackgroundModes

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Scroll down and you will see that you can enable      location in your info.plist

Good Luck with that one